# How to get send to email id not display name before send email c#

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin

How i get email id not display name like "javalp@gamil.com".

```
 var msg = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
 string messageTo = msg.To;
```

**Output:** messageTo = "Javal Patel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using To/CC/BCC properties, loop through all recipients in the MailItem.Recipients collection and read the Recipient.Address property. You might also want to use the Recipient.Type property (OlMailRecipientType.olTo/OlCC/olBCC) to figure out the recipient type.